# Do I authenticate at database level, at Flask User level, or both?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an MS-SQL deployed on AWS RDS, that I'm writing a Flask front end for. 
I've been following some intro Flask tutorials, all of which seem to pass the DB credentials in the connection string URI. I'm following the tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80#.e6b4mzs1l

For deployment, do I prompt for the DB login info and add to the connection string? If so, where? Using SQLAlchemy, I don't see any calls to create_engine (using the code in the tutorial), I just see an initialization using config.from_object, referencing the config.py where the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` is stored, which points to the DB location. Trying to call `config.update(dict(UID='****',                     PASSWORD='******'))` from my application has no effect, and looking in the config dict doesn't seem to have any applicable entries to set for this purpose. What am I doing wrong?

Or should I be authenticating using Flask-User, and then get rid of the DB level authentication? I'd prefer authenticating at the DB layer, for ease of use.

Comment: Are you planning on having Flask hook up to the db with individual users database credentials- so that each active user has their own connection?

Comment: Yes. So I'd prefer to define the users using the SQL authentication, rather than through Flask authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are using uses Flask-Sqlalchemy to abstract the database setup stuff, that's why you don't see engine.connect().

Frameworks like Flask-Sqlalchemy are designed around the idea that you create a connection pool to the database on launch, and share that pool amongst your various worker threads.  You will not be able to use that for what you are doing... it takes care of initializing the session and things early in the process.

Because of your requirements, I don't know that you'll be able to make any use of things like connection pooling.  Instead, you'll have to handle that yourself.  The actual connection isn't too hard...

```
engine = create_engine('dialect://username:password@host/db')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SOME SQL QUERY")
for row in result:
    # Do Something
connection.close()
```

The issue is that you're going to have to do that in every endpoint.  A database connection isn't something you can store in the session- you'll have to store the credentials there and do a connect/disconnect loop in every endpoint you write.  Worse, you'll have to either figure out encrypted sessions or server side sessions (without a db connection!) to prevent keeping those credentials in the session from becoming a horrible security leak.

I promise you, it will be easier both now and in the long run to figure out a simple way to authenticate users so that they can share a connection pool that is abstracted out of your app endpoints.  But if you HAVE to do it this way, this is how you will do it.  (make sure you are closing those connections every time!)

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you're advocating that I use Flask-Login or Flask-User or something equivalent. Then, because of that added auth layer, is it safe to keep the db user login info in the connection string in plaintext like that contained in the URI, or do I keep it somewhere else, or get rid of that DB auth layer altogether?

Comment: You can manage that database credential string as a secret- maybe an environment variable?  Using `MYSQL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '')` in your config lets you provide that at application launch time.  Another choice is to have a special config file that only lives on your production machine.